# Incorrect name saving to activeDocument path

Tags: save, jsx, photoshop-script

I have this script that saves out a .tif to the path PSD is open from.
The problem is that I cant for the life of me get it to save the file with a specific name. It always saves it as the PSD document name.

Please help, it's driving me insane.
(trying to save the file as "FOP")

```
PIA = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("PIA");
FOP= PIA.layerSets.getByName("FOP");
FOP.visible = true;

var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
    var desc255 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
        var desc256 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idBytO = charIDToTypeID( "BytO" );
        var idPltf = charIDToTypeID( "Pltf" );
        var idIBMP = charIDToTypeID( "IBMP" );
        desc256.putEnumerated( idBytO, idPltf, idIBMP );
        var idLZWC = charIDToTypeID( "LZWC" );
        desc256.putBoolean( idLZWC, true );
        var idsaveTransparency = stringIDToTypeID( "saveTransparency" );
        desc256.putBoolean( idsaveTransparency, true );
    var idTIFF = charIDToTypeID( "TIFF" );
    desc255.putObject( idAs, idTIFF, desc256 );
    var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
    desc255.putPath( idIn, activeDocument.path, new File("FOP"));
    var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
    desc255.putInteger( idDocI, 456 );
    var idLyrs = charIDToTypeID( "Lyrs" );
    desc255.putBoolean( idLyrs, false );
    var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
    var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
    var idsaveBegin = stringIDToTypeID( "saveBegin" );
    desc255.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveBegin );
executeAction( idsave, desc255, DialogModes.NO );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is similar to your other question: `putPath` only needs two arguments so it ignores `new File("FOP")` you're feeding to it. That line should look like this:

`desc255.putPath( idIn, new File(activeDocument.path + "/FOP.tif"));`

Also notice the `/` before the file name: `activeDocument.path` gives you a path without the final slash.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying to this as well. I managed to solve this based on your solution to my other question. I now have a working script that opens a file, replaces smart object in various groups and saves each group out as a .tif named correctly into the correct folder - I am very happy (Just nees a command to close photoshop now ;) ) Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: `photoshop.quit()` :)

Comment: I do have a query though. Is it possible in my above script to name the files based on data in a cell in a .csv file?